# Geometric isomers of substituted methylidenecyclohexane?

Tags: stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

[image]

**My thoughts on the problem:**
I am sort compound of sure  C and D will not show geometric isomerism because of the same groups (H and H) attached.
In compound A and B, suppose I swap the positions of H and Cl, I notice that it is not possible to obtain the new compound by rotation of the original one. 

**My doubt**: Does that mean A and B show geometric isomerism.  Also is my method, of interchanging the positions of H and Cl and checking if the same compound can be obtained by rotation, correct?

Comment: Related: [Why is 1-ethylidene-4-methylcyclohexane chiral?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58630/16683)

Comment: @orthocresol - Ohh ok. From that post I could conclude that D and C can not be correct answer. But I'm still confused between A and B. The solution given tells me the answer is only B.