# Why the C4 in this 1,3,4,5-substituted Cyclohexanes has a R/S configuration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality, cyclohexane

[image]
(1*S*,3*S*,4*S*,5*S*)-3,5-dimethoxy-1-phenylcyclohexane-1,4-dithiol.

ChemDraw21 shows the C4 is S configuration. However I think C4 has two same function groups(C3 and C5 are both S configuration; C2-1-6 and C6-1-2 are also the same).

So why C4 is chiral? where did I go a mistake?

Comment: OK, I seem to find how to name this, [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/96265/75243)

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answer is appreciated and it helps future readers.